# TikZ: naming paths in a \foreach and accessing them later

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, intersections

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (P1) at (60:4cm);
  \coordinate (P2) at (-20:4cm);

  \def\rad{1}

  \draw[name path global = line] (0, 0) -- (P1);

  \foreach \pos/\i in {(P1)/1, (P2)/2}{
    \draw[name path global = circ\i] \pos circle[radius = \rad];
  }

  \node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = line and circ1}] (P) at
  ($(intersection-1)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am told that `LaTeX` doesn't know the name `\circ1` and perhaps I misspelled it.  How can I access the named path for an intersection calculation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the brackets around `P1` and `P2` throw the `foreach` parser off: `\i` contains `(P1)` and `(P2)`, not `1` and `2`. You can fix this by removing the brackets:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (P1) at (60:4cm);
  \coordinate (P2) at (-20:4cm);

  \def\rad{1}

  \draw[name path global = line] (0, 0) -- (P1);

  \foreach \pos/\i in  {P1/1, P1/2}{
    \draw[name path global = circ\i] (\pos) circle[radius = \rad];
    \node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = line and circ\i}] (P) at
  (intersection-1) {};
  }


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

In the case of just finding the intersection of the line and only `circ2`, we can move the node out of the `\foreach` command and incorporate Qrrbrbrilbel's comment of using `/.expanded`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (P1) at (60:4cm);
  \coordinate (P2) at (-20:4cm);

  \def\rad{1}

  \draw[name path global = line] (0, 0) -- (P1);

  \foreach \pos/\i in  {P1/1, P1/2}{
    \draw[name path global/.expanded = circ\i] (\pos) circle[radius = \rad];
  }

  \node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = line and circ1}] (P) at
  (intersection-1) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @dustin: They do need to be in brackets, that's why I added them in the `\draw` line (note how it says `(\pos)` in my code, and just `\pos` in yours).

Comment: Can you add Qrrbrbirlbel's comment into your solution?  What I ended up doing was moving the node out of the `\foreach` and finding the intersection of `\circ1` and the `line` only.  So I need to use `name path global/.expanded=circ\i`.

Comment: @dustin: Feel free to edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use `(` and `)` to loop over coordinates without protecting the `,` (in Cartesian coordinates), you can say

```
\foreach \pos in {(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)}
   \fill \pos circle [radius=.5];
```

which will not split the list in eight ( `(0`, `0)`, `(0`, `1)`, etc.) elements but in four.

This is most likely more naturally to write then

```
\foreach \pos in {{(0,0)}, {(0,1)}, {(1,0)}, {(1,1)}}
   \fill \pos circle [radius=.5];
```

or even worse

```
\foreach \x/\y in {0/0, 0/1, 1/0, 1/1}
   \fill (\x,\y) circle [radius=.5];
```

which also would one hinder to use any other coordinate than Cartesian ones (you cannot input polar coordinates or named nodes or …).

The same thing happens with your already defined coordinates. The problem though is that `\foreach` only accepts this at the start of an element in the list *and* also throws away everything else coming after the `)` (making every other variable in the `/` list defaulting to the scanned coordinate).

Why this is implemented this way I don’t know but one can (at least for this example) “fix” this by issuing

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgffor@scanround(#1)#2,{\def\pgffor@value{(#1)#2}\pgffor@scanned}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble.

(Of course, you could have written your loop differently, say

```
\foreach \i in {1, 2}
  \draw[name path global/.expanded = circ\i] (P\i) circle[radius = \rad];
```

but that’s not the point of this question.)

The `/.expanded` handler is still needed, though.

### Code

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\def\pgffor@scanround(#1)#2,{\def\pgffor@value{(#1)#2}\pgffor@scanned}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (P1) at (60:4cm);
  \coordinate (P2) at (-20:4cm);

  \def\rad{1}

  \draw[name path global = line] (0, 0) -- (P1);

  \foreach \pos/\i in {(P1)/1, (P2)/2}
    \draw[name path global/.expanded = circ\i] \pos circle[radius = \rad];

  \node[coordinate, name intersections = {of = line and circ1}] (P) at  (intersection-1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```